# How to remove RAID option from HP DL360 Gen 9 for HDFS

Tags: raid, redhat, hp, hp-proliant, hadoop

I am setting up a brand new DL360 G9 Server for use in a Hadoop cluster proof-of-concept. As HDFS will be taking care of the RAID, I need to bypass this option in the G9 array controller (Smart Array P440ar). I just can't find where to do that - IF I can do that. The planned OS (RHEL 6.4) will not recognize the disks until they are config'd with the array controller.

It only allows me to set up an array with RAID 0. Is this the only way to install the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't the only way to set this server up.

You can set the RAID controller to use the "HBA mode", which turns it into a pure passthrough adapter for your disks. (helpful for Hadoop, ZFS, Storage Spaces, VMware vSAN...)

When you do this, the OS will see the individual drives. You may want to software RAID your OS disks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the G9 with Intelligent Provisioning (F10 at boot) you can set your array options.
Go to Configure and Install > Array configuration > Customize > Continue then the HP Smart Storage Admin tool will be the next screen.

Comment: I've tried that. The only option is to create an array with RAID 0 or 1.